# What is the use of the "java:" prefix when doing name lookup in jboss?

Tags: java, jboss, jms, jndi

I was running an application deployed on a JBoss server which contained jboss-messaging deployments. The application tried to connect to a jbossmq destination deployed on another JBoss server. I tried to use different connection factory JNDI name to create the connection and got different results.

1) the connection factory is "XAConnectionFactory". In this situation, the application can successfully connect to the jbossmq destination deployed on the remote JBoss server.

2) the connection factory is "java:/XAConnectionFactory". In this situation, the connection can not be created. The exception said the destination was not an object of javax.jms.Destination.

I guess in the situation #2, the connection factory in the local JVM (i.e. the jboss holds the jboss-messaging deployments) was used to connect to the remote jbossmq destination. But I can not prove this.

Does anybody know the usage of the "java:" prefix in this case? It's better to give some references about this topic since I googled a lot but did not find the answer :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's name of InitialContext type in JNDI. JNDI is like a phone book which can have numbers of People,Organisations,Gym etc etc. This is like saying give me number of person:adarliu. When it is local you do not need to do JNDI lookup but when it is remote you need it.